# Custom field is set to searchable, but not turning up results in the public directory on the frontend. Wildcard set to "yes" Help?

Tags: custom-fields, profile, joomla, custom-search, directory

I've created a public directory based on membership status. It displays information like org. name, phone, address, website, & products & services. The issue I'm having is that my custom field "products & services" isn't turning up in the search. I have it selected as a searchable field, but nothing turns up when typing a word that I know to be in one of our members products and services field.

The "name" search field works perfectly, but that is a standard civi field. Is there something further I need to do in order to make my custom field searchable other than selecting the searchable checkbox?

I've enabled the automatic wildcard. It should be automatically adding % to both front and end of search term. Is it different for custom fields?

If it matters, I'm using Joomla.

Comment: it might be worth seeing if you can replicate the problem on https://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/ and if you can, then share back here and someone may be able to look at your set up. i assume it would be minimal effort since you just need to create 1 x field, 1 x profile as 'proof of concept'

Comment: and confirm that your Custom Field is on 'contact' or a sub-contact-type or something else.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me, but I'm afraid It's much more difficult than simply creating a searchable custom field and adding it into a profile. I have done that and here is the link. https://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile/create&gid=14&reset=1

Comment: Now, it's actually making that custom field searchable from the front end when displayed in a directory with search capabilities?

Comment: So when the user fills out form A: Initial form (https://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile/create&gid=14&reset=1) it will add the user to smart group titled "Smart Search Group 1" which is displayed and reserved for profile "B: public display search field" found here (https://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile&force=1&gid=16) now there are keywords to search for in the custom field. Try editing search criteria and search for "products" which is entered in that field by an org. It doesn't show up.

Comment: Name search field works but not the custom field titled "search field?" It works if you use the wild card % before and after keyword your searching for. Now try to type in %products% it will bring up the org with "products" in that field. I want to know how to make this field searchable without the percentage symbols/wildcards for front end users?

Comment: I am not sure i follow but if you are quick, the 'fruit' field on https://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile&gid=14&reset=1 is doing a search and showing results if you choose 'banana'. give it a go. Notes. this is Profile "Use Listings Mode'  - i removed your 'smart group 1' filter from the profile as it was a potential point of confusion.

Comment: or via https://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile&gid=16&reset=1 but i get no results for '%products%' because afai can see you have no contacts with that info in your Smart Group (which is why i removed it for the other Profile to 'keep it simple'

Comment: ps Field has to be set as Searchable in both the Custom Field and in the Profile. not sure what you didn't have set or perhaps i am totally not getting the problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Joomla but it should be the same as Drupal / WordPress where you need to enable the permission "CiviCRM: access all custom data" for anonymous user.

[image]

Otherwise, you need to define an ACL to explicitly add the permission for everyone to the custom group containing the custom field. I feel that it's more complex and rarely needed but it depends on the permissions you have on your installation.

[image]